# How to add optgroup do dijit.form.Select or other widget type

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I need to create a "category" division in a dijit/dojo widget could be `dijit.form.Select` or another type.

The visual effect should be something like (when using optgroup):

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

My code:

```
require(["dijit/form/Select", "dojo/_base/window", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Select, win){
    new Select({
        name: "select2",
        options: [
            { label: "Volvo", value: "volvo" },
            { label: "Saab", value: "saab", selected: true },
            { label: "Mercedes", value: "mercedes" },
            { label: "Audi", value: "audi" }
        ]
    }).placeAt(win.body()).startup();
});
```

Comment: I'think you've already the anwer ;)

Answer (score 0):

As far I know `optgroup` it should not be supported directly in dijit.
But you can achieve a visually similar effecting adding HTML markup in the property `label`.

Example using `<i>` tag which make the entry in the widget italic (you can add there really what you like, even an image and style it using CSS):

```
require(["dijit/form/Select", "dojo/_base/window", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Select, win){
    new Select({
        name: "select2",
        options: [
            { label: "<i>Swedish Cars</i>", value: "" },
            { label: "Volvo", value: "volvo" },
            { label: "Saab", value: "saab", selected: true },
            { label: "<i>German Cars</i>", value: "" },
            { label: "Mercedes", value: "mercedes" },
            { label: "Audi", value: "audi" }
        ]
    }).placeAt(win.body()).startup();
});
```

---

**Edit:**

In order to find a solution to this problem for one of mine projects, I have created a new component dedicated [dijit-select-optgroup](https://github.com/gibbok/dijit-select-optgroup) (MIT license).

> SelectOptgroup is a styleable, searchable drop down select box for
>   Dojo which includes grouping of options (similar to html 
>   element with ).

[A demo is visible here](https://gibbok.github.io/dijit-select-optgroup/).

Example of usage:

```
var instance = new SelectOptgroup({
    options: [
        {
            label: 'Optgroup item',
            value: '',
            optgroup: true // mark menu item as optgroup
        },
        {
            label: 'Option item',
            value: 'option '// mark menu item as option
        },
        {
            label: '', // empty strings mark menu item as separator
            value: ''
        },
        {
            label: '<div class="SelectOptgroup__nested"><span class="select__icon">Icon Text</span></div>', // html allowed in menu item
            value: 'grunt'
        }
    ]
}, 'domId');
```

---

Alternative solution:
http://vafada.github.io/chosen-dojo/